# How to return a break or Continue in a method is it possible?

Tags: java, break, continue

When I'm using while loop I need to use many if blocks which are exactly same So I planed to put it in a method and reuse it where I want! but I had a problem I want to return Continue or break in some area of my if blocks so can I return Break or continue?

```
while (true){
move(a);
move(b);
}

public *** move(Parameter parameter){
  if (statement){
    return continue;
  }
  else{
    return break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I always found those uses bad design, so if those instruction are not in the loop directly, what a mess

Comment: Also, if I an not mistaken, move(b) will never be executed since `contìnue` stop this statement block and recheck the loop value.

Comment: @AxelH: you are correct; `move(b)` would be unreachable if we interpret `continue` literally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return a boolean:

```
while (true){
    if(move(a))
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        continue;
    }
    if(move(b))
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        continue;
    }
}

public boolean move(Parameter parameter){
    if (statement){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @yper yes there is...If `move(a)` returns `false` he wants to skip `move(b)`.

Comment: @yper this might not be his entire code...he might just be showing an example so he might have code after `move(b)` that he wants to skip.

Comment: @khelwood yes that is true...but that was his question. Maybe he has more code that we can't see. That is a different subject all together and maybe a different question...

Comment: @khelwood this answers his question. Now if he has another question he can post that here also.

Comment: thank you! I'm disturbed about the conditions but i forgot that we can make any number of statements using Boolean!

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to set aside the fact if we implemented what you want literally then `move(b);` would be *unreachable*. Presumably when you say `continue` you mean execute the next statement; not return to the start of the loop?

But sadly you can't achieve this in Java. In Java, you can only return a *value*, not an "instruction". (In C and C++ you *can* contrive this using a macro, although that messes up your debugger.)

However, if you adapt `move` to return a `boolean` which is say `true` if you want to `break` and `false` otherwise, then at the call site you could write

```
while (true){
    if(move(a)){
        break;
    } else if (move(b)){
        break;
    }
}
```

or ace it with

```
while (true){
    if (move(a) || move(b)){
        break;
    }
}
```

where I'm exploiting the *short-circuiting* nature of the operator `||`.

Finally, if you want to submit this code to an obfuscation contest then use the simply beautiful but still comprehensible

`while (!(move(a) || move(b)));`

and if you want to guarantee that you win said contest, then swap the return rule of `move` round and use the utterly indecent

`while (move(a) && move(b))`;

Comment: The usage of `||` is actually not that dumb. +1

Comment: Hear that Bathsheba? Not a dumb move at all ;)

Comment: Do you really think this is sad?

Comment: There is one thing that I would point out. His example state something equivalent to `return statement ? break : continue` so move(b) would be unreachable (compile error). (Am I clear ?)

Comment: Yes you are. I try to disclaim that at the top of the answer.

Comment: @xehpuk: terribly ;-) . In C++ we could do this using *actors*.

Answer (score 0):

Make it super simple with a returning boolean

```
public boolean move(Parameter parameter){
  return statement;
} 

while (true){
  if(!move(a)) break;
  if(!move(b)) break;
}
```

Comment: That's not *quite* the same. See my answer ;-)